# How to select cells greater than a value in a multi-index Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Try 1:

`df[ df > 1.0 ]` : this returned all cells in `NAN`.

Try2:

`df.loc[ df > 1.0 ]` : this returned `KeyError: 0`

`df[df['A']> 1.0]` : this works - But I want to apply the filter condition to all columns.

Comment: what filter condition do you want to apply , what is an example `df` and what are you expecting as output? When trying it for whole df, there would surely be some rows where only some columns meet the condition (and vice-versa) , so for places where the condition is not met, it is substituted with `NaN` .

Comment: Are you trying to select rows where any column satisfies the condition? or where all columns satisfy the condition?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I want to select rows where any column satisfies the condition. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is to select only rows where any one column meets the condition , you can use [`DataFrame.any()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) along with `axis=1` (to do row-wise grouping) . Example -

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  5
2  3  1  4

In [6]: df[(df <= 2).any(axis=1)]
Out[6]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
2  3  1  4
```

Alternatively, if you are trying for filtering rows where all columns meet the condition , use [`.all()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) inplace of [`.any()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) . Example of `all` -

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[3,1,4],[1,2,1]],columns=['A','B','C'])

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  5
2  3  1  4
3  1  2  1

In [11]: df[(df <= 2).all(axis=1)]
Out[11]:
   A  B  C
3  1  2  1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question where the dataframe has a multi-index.